# building flink 1.10 encountered a package not found error

Tags: apache-flink

I am importing `flink` source code to IDEA as the official website guide

> error:org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl does not exist
>
> description:the error resulted from an import in the interface
>   org.apache.flink.sql.parser.utils.ParseResource

the import line is:

```
org.apache.flink.sql.impl.ParseException
```

I looked up for the "**impl**" package in the path but did not found it actually, I am not sure if I did something wrong following the steps, tell me if you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts are generated through maven plugins. Make sure you either run a full `mvn install` locally before importing, or use IntelliJ generate source feature

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have done the operation "generate sources" in IDEA following the official guide and an error occurred while I am building ptoject.Since others did not have this problem,I will try it again or use mvn install  to see if it is ok this time.